How to get absolute values instead of percentages for heap memory in async-profiler?
I am running this command in a remote server to profile :
./asprof -e alloc -d 30 -f ./flamegraph.html 8873

I want to see the memory consumption in MB (megabytes) instead of percentages.
Based of PID I am running async-profiler for that Java process.
How to do this in asprof (async-profiler)?
